# How to find the time when a Puppet manifest is executed

Tags: puppet

I'm wondering if anyone knows a good way to get the date and time when a portion of code in a Puppet manifest is actually *executed*.  Sometimes my manifests take a long time to run, and I need to schedule a task to occur soon after the end of the run, no matter when that occurs.

I have tried the `time()` function, setting a variable using `generate()` (using the date function on the Puppet master), and even creating a custom fact, but everything I've tried gets evaluated when the manifests are *parsed* on the server, rather than when they actually execute on the client.

Any ideas?  The clients are all Windows, FWIW.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you mean, but you can't get this information during catalog compilation (obviously), so you can't use it to change the way the catalog will be applied.

If you need to trigger another process on the same host, then you should use any IPC mechanism you have available. You can `exec` anything, and have it happen just after any other resources is applied, so it is just a matter of finding the proper command.